# std::map and operations of amortized O(log N)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, c++17

I have an assignment in which I must implement the insert member function for a data structure impemented on top of std::map.
This member function has 3 parameters: firstKey, secondKey, valToInsert.

The assignment specifies not to make more than 2 operations of amortized O(log N), in contrast to O(1), in which N is the number of elements in map.

I wrote the code, it compiles and works as it should.
I am not sure about these 2 operations, though.

I can not show the entire code (since it is part of the assignment), so I will only list the map's member function I used.
They are:

- one `auto firtstIt = map.lower_bound(firstKey);`
- one `auto secondtIt = map.lower_bound(secondKey);`
- one `map.insert(secondIt, {secondKey, valToInsert});`
- one `map.insert_or_assign(firstIt, firstKey, valToInsert);`
- one `map.erase(std::next(firstKey), secondKey);`
- several `map.erase(it);` where "several" depends on the distance between firstIt and secondIt

Did I meet the condition imposed by the task? If not, why?

Comment: what are properties of `firstKey` and `secondKey`? Are they completely random?

Comment: @MarekR They are copyable, assignable, and less-than comparable via operator<. I also know that firstKey < secondKey

Comment: You can't do `map.lower_bound(firstKey);` and `map.lower_bound(secondKey);` since this is what simple `insert` does. Note `insert` returns an iterator, which can be used as a hint for second insert.

Comment: @MarekR I know `insert` returns the iterator (in fact, I used this returned iterator). Nevertheless, I must do lower_bound since I need to make some calculations on the iterator this function returns before the insertion.

Comment: @MarekR My doubt is wheter I met the condition imposed by the task on the 2 operations of amortized O(log N).

Comment: if distance of firstIt and secondIt is N, then you are in `O(N)` (but cannot be less). Else seems ok.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have no control over firstIt and secondIt, but I think it is reasonable to suppose that they are "close".

Comment: You never explained what outcome this member function with three parameters is supposed to achieve. Also, you seem to be saying that you are allowed to use an arbitrary number of `O(1)` operations. That's a strange requirement; anything you can do by calling a `map` member function working in `O(log N)` time, you can do less efficiently by using `O(N)` operations taking `O(1)` time each (but you wouldn't use up your "two `logN` operations" quota).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The function must check some conditions on firstKey and secondKey (wheter they are both less than the first key, or if the keys are present in the map). Depending on this condition, I have to do simple stuff in the first case. In the second case I must insert (if not present) the second key, and insert or update the first key. Finally I have to erase all the keys in between and return. Hope it could help.
I am sorry, I am not yet very confident with complexity and did not understand the second part of your answer.

Comment: You claim the assignment says, and I quote, "not to make more than 2 operations of amortized O(log N), in contrast to O(1)". What does "in contrast" mean here? Does it mean that you are allowed to make an arbitrary number of `O(1)` operations? Because if that's the case, you can avoid using any `O(logN)` operations at all; e.g. instead of `find` or `lower_bound`, you could just iterate over the map and compare your key to each element one by one. That's less efficient, but it only uses `O(1)` operations of which you are apparently allowed as many as you want.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, I got what you kindly explained. The assignment also specifies that, for std::map, the overload of functions like insert/erase are ammortized O(logN) if they need to find the element position, and are ammortized O(1) if a correct iterator is passed to the function. And the assignment specifhies that no more than "necessary" O(1) operations must be done. So, I think that an arbitrary number of O(1) operations are not allowed. Bak to my opening message, I still do not get if only the first two call are ammortized O(logN) while the other are fine with the assignment condition.